# Microsoft Teams Bot and custom app screen flickering

Tags: microsoft-teams

I've a Teams bot that is sharing a video feed to all the users in the meeting (this part is working fine)
But when this bot is running in the meeting and a user will try to share a stage app (like Figma) the screen will start to flicker like teams client isn't able to choose what should be displayed and it constantly switching from bot to Figma. When Bot leaves the meeting or Figma screen share is stopped everything is working fine.

This is happening both on Windows(version 23320.3027.2591.1505) and Mac OS X.

I've tested other apps that has possibility to be shared and it's behaving the same.

Comment: Screen flickering in Microsoft Teams Bot and custom app can occur due to various reasons.
Rendering issues: Ensure that your app's UI elements are properly rendered and optimized for performance. Avoid excessive DOM manipulation or frequent updates to the UI.
Network latency: If your app relies on fetching data from external sources or APIs, network latency can cause screen flickering. 
Inefficient code:  Review your codebase and identify any performance bottlenecks. Use efficient algorithms and data structures to improve the overall performance of your app.

Comment: Compatibility issues: Ensure that your app is compatible with the Teams platform and follows the recommended guidelines. Check for any known compatibility issues or conflicts with other apps or plugins installed in Teams.
Browser compatibility:  Ensure that your app is compatible with the browser version used by Teams. Test your app on different browsers and versions to identify any browser-specific issues.